# Variable not being reset when passed into a function

Tags: python-3.x

Kind of confused as to why my variable `params` is saving/holding its state after it's passed into a function. Here's what I'm running:

```
assessment_ids = [1,2,3]
params = {'page': 1, 'limit': 100, 'date':'2020-06-01'}
for assessment in assessment_ids:
    params['assessment_id'] = assessment
    get_data(base_url, client, oauth, api_endpoint, params)
```

Basically, at the end of `get_data`, `page`'s value is set at some higher number, but I want to start over at page 1 at each iteration of the loop. So on the second loop iteration, I would want `params = {'page': 1, 'limit': 100, 'date':'2020-06-01', 'assessment_id': 2}`

The function `get_data` does indeed update the `params` variable, but why is it being saved/held/preserved back in this scope? I thought for every loop iteration, params would be reset to `params = {'page': 1, 'limit': 100, 'date':'2020-06-01'}` and then the `assessment_id` updated. Should I add a `return params = {'page': 1, 'limit': 100, 'date':'2020-06-01'}` at the end of the `get_data` function?

Comment: Why would `params` be reset to `{'page': 1, 'limit': 100, 'date':'2020-06-01'}` each loop iteration? You only set it to that before the loop. If you move the `params =` line to inside the loop, it will happen each iteration.

Answer (score 0):

See this simple (and stupid) example:

```
foo={"a":1}

def add(f):
    f["a"] += 1

add(foo)
print(foo) # will print {"a":2}
```

You'll need to either provide a copy of your dictionary so you don't mutate the original dictionary, or find another way to not mutate it, maybe move `params` into the for loop as well. (your suggestion should do the trick, although I'd prefer to copy or move into for loop it since it's a small dictionary).